# How to pass file to a function

Tags: php, forms

I have a HTML form, that contains a bunch of text inputs and one file input. My text inputs pass just fine into my function, however the file doesn't work the same way. Here's what I am trying to pass:

```
$submit = submit_server($_POST['name'], $_POST['ip'], $_FILES['banner'], $_POST['description'], $_POST['slots'], $_POST['tags']);
```

Here is what the function takes:

```
submit_server($name, $ip, $banner, $description, $slots, $tags)
```

Here is my form:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
    ...some text inputs...
    <input type="file" name="banner" />
</form>
```

Is there something I need to change to make this work? Within my function, I check for the file with `if(!$banner){ return false; }` and it returns false.

I just need to pass the whole file object into my function. Thanks!

Comment: if you debug with `print_r($_FILES);` you will see the problem

Comment: @Dagon I see that the array is empty... `Array ( )` What do I do from there? I'm very confused :/

Comment: then there is no file, please post the code for your form, i bet your missing **enctype="multipart/form-data"**

Comment: Oh, I didn't have that. I added it, but I still get a problem. My form has been added to the OP. EDIT: Nevermind, it works. If you want to post your answer as a solution, I can accept it :) Thanks!

Comment: so what's the new problem ? is the $_FILES array now populated ?

Comment: Nevermind, it works. If you want to post your answer as a solution, I can accept it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all forms that are used for submitting files must have

**enctype="multipart/form-data"**

in the form tag, please see manual section: [Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Answer (score 1):

u must use:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and a small advise for you.

Why did you pass all variables like this?

create array and pass it to the function.

```
<?php
      $data = array(
                     'name'=> $_POST['name'],
                      'ip'=> $_POST['ip'], 
                    );
       submit_server($data);   //i think, this is a good practise
```